# How to know that provided URL is Image or Video in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, url

I am Using Firebase as Database where user can Upload Image or Video so I am Fetching URL from my database so I am getting two URLs one of them can be either video or image so what can I do to detect the URL.

Let Suppose this is the URL.
[This is the example URL. NOTE URL can be different](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/purple-e-commerce.appspot.com/o/hhhhhhh.mp4?alt=media&token=9938aba0-4b79-4192-8f93-b04c60021827)

any help will be appreciated

### Edited

for better understanding I will providing some example code:

```
MyUserModel model; //this is the model class where I can get the url in String

String Url = model.getUrl(); //its URL can be video or image

//Can I write something like this:

//does any method like this : isVideo();
// if the url is video then this function will return true else false;

if(isVideo(Url)){
 videoView.setVideoPath(Url); //and other stuffs
}else{
  Glide.with(context).load(Url).into(ImagView); //something like this.
}

 ...
```

> NOTE : SOME URLS DON'T HAVE EXTENTIONS LIKE `PNG`, `MP4`, `JPG` ETC. I am saying this because I have a some URLs with no extension related to mp4 or png etc.

Comment: I will suggest you to have one column named as "type" and keep 0 for image and 1 for video when you are saving image/video into data base. This way you can recognise the type easily.

Comment: @Parmesh Yeah u are right but user have choice to upload either Video or Image so please can you give me answer of my question.

Comment: You may need to tweak UI little bit. You can provide an option to capture image from UI and launch camera app only to capture image. Similarly provide an option to capture only video. This way you can make sure at front end user is capturing either image or video at a time. Save that type value in firebase db as per my comment above.

Comment: @Parmesh Your First Suggestion is Nice I can do this when choosing image to upload thank you for your wonderful response.

Comment: You can use urlconnection to get content type from ur url but i think this might not work in every case.

Comment: Give this a try and see if it works for url without extension or not.   URLConnection conn = url.connect();
String type = conn.getContentType();

Comment: @Danish `url.connect();` is not working means I am getting Error. by the way I am getting the url in string so How could it work. thank you for your response

Comment: I am not sure this will work or not but you can give this a try:  
                       MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Url)

Comment: @Danish I will give this a try.

Comment: @Danish can you tell me what will return that code ie - `String` or `something` becasue when I am logging this  it is printing `Nothing`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238451/discussion-between-jack-sparrow-and-danish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to have one column named as "type" and keep 0 for image and 1 for video when you are saving image/video into data base. This way you can recognise the type easily.

You may need to tweak UI little bit. You can provide an option to capture image from UI and launch camera app only to capture image. Similarly provide an option to capture only video. This way you can make sure at front end user is capturing either image or video at a time. Save that type value in firebase db as above.

Comment: Your answer was correct for me but according to my question, this answer is not correct.